# Link ajax load php and refresh div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a system to upload images, but I would like to add the option to rotate the image using Ajax, the problem is that if the full page update variable session is lost, then only need to update the div where the image is located.

I can not use form because the link is in a form, so it has to be this way, if possible ...

This is what I'm trying:

**index.php**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>  
...  
<form>   

...

<div id="thumbs">
<?php
 if(isset($_SESSION['sess_img'])){
  echo '
   <a href="#" class="link" data-artid="'.$_SESSION['sess_img'].'">Rotate</a>
  ';
 }
?>
</div>

...

</form>

...

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.link').click(function(){
        var elem = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "rotate.php",
            data: "file="+elem.attr('data-artid'),
            success: function(result) {
             $("#thumbs").html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

**rotate.php**

```
<?php 
 session_start();
 $route = 'uploads/img/'; 
 $file = $_GET['file'];     
 rotateImage($route.$file, $route.$file, 90); 
?>
```

**The idea:**

1. Click the link.
2. Process rotate.php
3. Update thumbs div

**Issue:**

This code does nothing, it does not fail, but not run the PHP.

Comment: What is the specific problem or question? You provided some code with no indication of what is or isn't working

Comment: Can't you rotate to the user using css if the ajax call was successful? Like adding `transform: rotate(90deg)`, that way you wouldn't need to refresh the page if the user wants to simply rotate the picture.

Comment: @charlietfl Issue:
This code does nothing, it does not fail, but not run the PHP.

Comment: @LucasLazaro The problem is that the image shown is the image already loaded on the server, the rotateImage () function does is rotate the image directly on the server (the file uploads) as the image is uploaded tmb by ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your `rotate.php` code is not right. Check out this example. Maybe it'll help you out : http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php#refsect1-function.imagerotate-examples